# Large mysql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, large-data

I have a large table of about 14 million rows. Each row has contains a block of text. I also have another table with about 6000 rows and each row has a word and six numerical values for each word. I need to take each block of text from the first table and find the amount of times each word in the second table appears then calculate the mean of the six values for each block of text and store it.

I have a debian machine with an i7 and 8gb of memory which should be able to handle it. At the moment I am using the php substr_count() function. However PHP just doesn't feel like its the right solution for this problem. Other than working around time-out and memory limit problems does anyone have a better way of doing this? Is it possible to use just SQL? If not what would be the best way to execute my PHP without overloading the server?

Comment: So you're basically rewriting an indexer like [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be done in pure SQL. Can you put up the exact table structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do each record from the 'big' table one-at-a-time. Load that single 'block' of text into your program (php or what ever), and do the searching and calculation, then save the appropriate values where ever you need them.

Do each record as its own transaction, in isolation from the rest. If you are interrupted, use the saved values to determine where to start again.

Once you are done the existing records, you only need to do this in the future when you enter or update a record, so it's much easier. You just need to take your big bite right now to get the data updated.

Comment: This is how I did it in the end. It does a thousand rows then calls itself again to do the next thousand and spits out how long it took. Currently doing 1000 every 20 seconds so should take about three days. Its only using one core but time is no object so I think I will just leave it be.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do exactly? If you are trying to create something like a search engine with a weighting function, you maybe should drop that and instead use the MySQL fulltext search functions and indices that are there. If you still need to have this specific solution, you can of course do this completely in SQL. You can do this in one query or with a trigger that is run each time after a row is inserted or updated. You wont be able to get this done properly with PHP without jumping through a lot of hoops.

To give you a specific answer, we indeed would need more information about the queries, data structures and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry if I am not explaining myself properly. I just want to run the query one time to go through and generate the six mean values of all the words matched from the database of 6000 words for each of the 14 million paragraphs of text. 

So I would have my 14 million rows but I would add 6 more columns to each row with the mean value of all the words that were found in the  body of text.

Answer (score 0):

Redesign IT()

If for size on disc is not !important just joints table into one

---

Table with 6000 put into memory [ memory table ] and make backup every one hour

INSERT IGNORE into back.table SELECT * FROM my.table;

---

Create "own" index in big table eq

Add column "name index" into big table with id of row

-- 
Need more info about query to find solution

Comment: I have added an index to the big table and I was considering adding the other table to memory. At the moment I just look for an id in the big table then for each row in the other table do a substr_count(). But I want to run the query for each ID in the large table and I think just doing a SELECT * would cause timeout or memory limit problems?

Comment: Why you nad make "pre as column value" make str_count and strlen and write to into DB